# Proving $r_n\le r_l s^{n-l}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $r_n=n^k |q|^n$ for natural $n$ and $k$ and $q$ be a constant. How can I prove that $r_n\le r_l s^{n-l}$ where $n\ge l$ and $s=r_{n+1}/r_n$?

**What I tried**
$$s=\frac{r_{n+1}}{r_n}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^k |q|\le\left(1+\frac{1}{l}\right)^k |q|$$
but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: You select values of $q,k$ prior correct? Are there any other restrictions on those values?

Comment: Correct. $k$ is a natural number and $q$ is a complex number.

Comment: First of all finding an upper bound for $s$ does not help here, since you want to show that it is larger. To solve you problem what you want to do is rearrange the inequality to read $\frac{r_n}{r_l} \leq s^{n-l}$. You have already computed $s$. So now compute $\frac{r_n}{r_l}$ and compare to $s^{n-l}$

Comment: Doing out the inequality in terms of $n,q,k$ I found that the terms of $q$ cancel each other out. You can likely numerically solve from there

Comment: @StiftungWarentest I got $\frac{r_n}{r_l s^{n-l}}=\frac{n^k}{l^k}\frac{l^{k(n-l)}}{(l+1)^{k(n-l)}}$, how can I prove it to be $\le 1$?

Comment: @StiftungWarentest Or how can I prove $\frac{n}{l}\le\left(1+\frac{1}{l}\right)^{n-l}$ for $n\ge l$?